# Why is my homemade pulse transformer so inefficient?

Tags: transformer

I built this transformer core out of 30 mm mild steel. It is 13 cm by 8 cm. The primary winding is 30 meters of #29 wire, and the secondary is 60 meters of #29 wire. The windings measure 5 ohms and 10 ohms. A 100-ohm resistor is across each winding to absorb voltage spikes.

When I apply a 15 volt pulse to the primary, the secondary only produces 5 volts. The core will have eddy currents, and is not the most efficient design, but 17% efficiency seems overly low. I tried resetting the core magnetic field by applying reverse voltage, but it has no effect on the output.

The 15 volts on the primary seems to produce a very strong magnetic field, the pieces of steel are locked together when it is energized. But this field does not seem to induce any significant voltage in the secondary.

Am I having massive hysteresis loss?

What modifications do you suggest to get the output at least above 80%?
[image: Transformer]

Comment: Without insulated laminations, the core is just a huge shorted turn.

Comment: What are the characteristics of your pulse, pulse width, rep-rate?

Comment: What is the output impedance of your pulse generator?

Comment: I don't have any experience with power pulse transformers, yet. (I do have an interest in one used to impedance-match rocket squibs to a triggered xenon tube output, though.) For signal types, though, I know the main ideas are to try and minimize parasitic elements: leakage inductance, winding capacitance, etc. And a ferrite core is almost always used as the higher-frequency components in the signal also have to cross over well. What in the heck are you trying to achieve with this? Is this a power pulse application for heating or something?

Comment: It is for a switching power supply using multiple inputs. I have ordered some laminated block cores, and will post the results. 
https://images.app.goo.gl/DLCngowY37YubG6y5

Answer (score 5):

> *The core will have eddy currents, and is not the most efficient
> design, but 17% efficiency seems overly low.*

Not at all. I believe that most of the coupling losses you see are due to **not** having laminations. This is why people use laminations or ferrite cores.

> *The 15 volts on the primary seems to produce a very strong magnetic
> field, the pieces of steel are locked together when it is energized.
> But this field does not seem to induce any significant voltage in the
> secondary.*

If the applied voltage is constant then there won't be an induced voltage once the primary current has settled to a constant value. It will settle to a constant value due to the coil resistance.

> *Am I having massive hysteresis loss?*

No, you are having a massive eddy current loss.

> *What modifications do you suggest to get the output at least above
> 80%?*

Try some ferrite core material or use laminated silicon steel.